# Revit C#: Copy existing button to my Ribbon

Tags: c#, api, ribbon, autodesk, revit

I want to use the Create-Wall-Button from Architecture in my Ribbon.
I've tried debugging and found the splitbutton here: `Autodesk.Windows.ComponentManager.Ribbon.Tabs[0].Panels[1].Source.Items[0]`

How can I copy this SplitButton to my Ribbon or what I have to call in a new Button to use this function?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is posible to clone an built-in command button and add it to another tab, however you would need a couple of tricks and of course the non-supported `Autodesk.Windows` dll.

I think what you are looking for is the method `PostCommand` from the `UIApplication`. Just create a new command and the requested Postable Command will be executed after your own command is completed:

```
var app = cmdData.Application;
var cmdId = RevitCommandId.LookupPostableCommandId(PostableCommand.StructuralWall);
app.PostCommand(cmdId);
```

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I was looking for.